# Как очистить форму при перезагрузке страницы (django)?

Tags: python, html, django, форма

Пытаюсь осилить django.
При перезагрузке страницы в поля формы не очищаются, в них остаются ранее введенные данные. Как с этим бороться?

Пример кода:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    num1 = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=100, label='Число 1 ')
    num2 = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=100, label='Число 2 ')

def simple(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
        n1 = int(request.POST.get('num1'))
        n2 = int(request.POST.get('num2'))
        result = n1 * n2
        return render(request, 'example.html', {'form': my_form, 'result': result})
    else:
        my_form = ExampleForm()
        return render(request, 'example.html', {'form': my_form})
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Расчет</button>
    </form>

   <br>
<div>Результат: {{result}}  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто при POST запросе делайте редирект после сохранения формы

```
def simple(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
        n1 = int(request.POST.get('num1'))
        n2 = int(request.POST.get('num2'))
        result = n1 * n2
        return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        my_form = ExampleForm()
        return render(request, 'example.html', {'form': my_form})
```

Comment: в таком случае я при нажатии кнопки  "Расчет" получаю обновленную страницу с пустыми полями и без результата вычисления. 
Хотелось бы, чтоб при "Расчете" значения полей и результат отображались, а при перезагрузке страницы - обнулялись. Но спасибо большое за подсказку, может, самостоятельно осилю.

Comment: тогда перенаправляйте на GET запрос с передачей данных формы